# raspberry pi not sending to windowsform

Tags: c#

Any idea why my visual studio doesn't send to `windowsform` from pi but it does send when i'm using my school's **visual studio** ( same version ). Do I have to download any specific thing or whatsoever to make it work? Please help.

Here's my code in case too. Would be cool if some1 can go through it and help me with it ( school's project ) Much appreciated !

```
 string strConnectionString =
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataCommsDBConnection"].ConnectionString;

    DataComms dataComms;

    public delegate void myprocessDataDelegate(string strData);

    private void saveWaterSensorDataToDB(string strTime, string strWaterValue, string strStatus)
    {
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

        string strCommandText = "INSERT MySensor (TimeOccurred, SensorValue, SensorStatus) +" +
            "VALUES (@time, @value, @status)";

        SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
        updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", strTime);
        updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", strWaterValue);
        updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", strStatus);

        myConnect.Open();

        int result = updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        myConnect.Close();
    }

    private string extractStringValue(string strData, string ID)
    {
        string result = strData.Substring(strData.IndexOf(ID) + ID.Length);
        return result;
    }

    private float extractFloatValue(string strData, string ID)
    {
        return (float.Parse(extractStringValue(strData, ID)));
    }

    private void handleWaterSensorData(string strData, string strTime, string ID)
    {
        string strWaterValue = extractStringValue(strData, ID);

        txtWaterValue.Text = strWaterValue;
        txtWaterLevel.Text = strWaterValue;

        float fWaterValue = extractFloatValue(strData, ID);
        string status = "";
        if (fWaterValue <= 500)
            status = "Dry";
        else
            status = "Wet";
        txtRoomStatus.Text = status;


    }

    private void handleButtonData(string strData, string strTime, string ID)
    {
        string strbuttonValue = extractStringValue(strData, ID);

        txtButtonValue.Text = strbuttonValue;
        txtDoorBell.Text = strbuttonValue;
    }

    private void extractSensorData(string strData, string strTime)
    {
        if (strData.IndexOf("WaterLevel=") != -1)
            handleWaterSensorData(strData, strTime, "WaterLevel=");
        else if (strData.IndexOf("BUTTON=") != -1)
            handleButtonData(strData, strTime, "BUTTON=");
    }

    public void handleSensorData(string strData)
    {
        string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        extractSensorData(strData, dt);

        string strMessage = dt + ":" + strData;
        lbDataComms.Items.Insert(0, strMessage);

    }

    public void processDataReceive(string strData)
    {
        myprocessDataDelegate d = new myprocessDataDelegate(handleSensorData);
        lbDataComms.Invoke(d, new object[] { strData });
    }

    public void commsDataReceive(string dataReceived)
    {
        processDataReceive(dataReceived);
    }

    public void commsSendError(string errMsg)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(errMsg);
        processDataReceive(errMsg);
    }

    private void InitComms()
    {
        dataComms = new DataComms();
        dataComms.dataReceiveEvent += new DataComms.DataReceivedDelegate(commsDataReceive);
        dataComms.dataSendErrorEvent += new DataComms.DataSendErrorDelegate(commsSendError);
    }



    public frmDataComms()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmDataComms_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitComms();
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbDataComms.Items.Clear();
    }

    private void btnSendLight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataComms.sendData("SENDWATER");
    }

    private void btnSendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataComms.sendData("SENDBUTTON");
    }

    private void btnCmd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataComms.sendData(txtCmd.Text);
    }

    private void btnSendAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataComms.sendData("SENDALL");
    }

    private void btnSendTemp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataComms.sendData("SENDTEMP");
    }
}
```

---

Form ***

```
namespace DataCommsRpi
{
public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    const int MODE_SENDWATER = 1;
    const int MODE_SENDBUTTON = 2;
    const int MODE_SENDALL = 3;
    const int MODE_SENDTEMP = 4;
    static int curMode;

    Pin waterPin = Pin.AnalogPin2;
    IButtonSensor button = DeviceFactory.Build.ButtonSensor(Pin.DigitalPin4);
    Pin tempPin = Pin.AnalogPin0;

    DataComms dataComms;

    string strDataReceived = "";

    private bool buttonPressed = false;
    private bool prevButtonStatus = false;

    int moistureAdcValue = 800;
    double tempDegree = 20;
    private bool moistureWet = false;
    private bool moistureDry = false;
    private bool tempHot = false;
    private bool tempCold = false;

    private void Sleep(int NoOfMs)
    {
        Task.Delay(NoOfMs).Wait();
    }

    private async void startWaterMonitoring()
    {
        int iPrevAdcValue = 800, iReadAdcValue, iDiff;
        await Task.Delay(100);
        while (true)
        {
            Sleep(500);
            iReadAdcValue = DeviceFactory.Build.GrovePi().AnalogRead(waterPin);
            if (iPrevAdcValue > iReadAdcValue)
                iDiff = iPrevAdcValue - iReadAdcValue;
            else
                iDiff = iReadAdcValue - iPrevAdcValue;
            iPrevAdcValue = iReadAdcValue;
            if (iDiff < 100)
                moistureAdcValue = iReadAdcValue;
        }

    }

    private async void startTempMonitoring()
    {

        await Task.Delay(100);
        int adcValue; double tempCalculated = 0, R;

        while (true)
        {
            Sleep(1000);
            adcValue = DeviceFactory.Build.GrovePi().AnalogRead(tempPin);

            int B = 4250, R0 = 100000;
            R = 100000 * (1023.0 - adcValue) / adcValue;
            tempCalculated = 1 / (Math.Log(R / R0) / B + 1 / 298.15) - 273.15;
            if (!Double.IsNaN(tempCalculated))
                tempDegree = tempCalculated;


        }

    }

    private async void startButtonMonitoring()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        while(true)
        {
            Sleep(100);
            string buttonState = button.CurrentState.ToString();
            if (buttonState.Equals("On"))
            {
                Sleep(100);
                buttonState = button.CurrentState.ToString();
                if(buttonState.Equals("On"))
                {
                    buttonPressed = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void commsDataReceive(string dataReceived)
    {
        strDataReceived = dataReceived;
        Debug.WriteLine("Data Received : " + strDataReceived);
    }

    private void sendDataToWindows(string strDataOut)
    {
        try
        {
            dataComms.sendData(strDataOut);
            Debug.WriteLine("Sending Msg : " + strDataOut);
        }

        catch(Exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ERROR. Did you forget to initComms()?");
        }
    }

    private void initComms()
    {
        dataComms = new DataComms();
        dataComms.dataReceiveEvent += new DataComms.DataReceivedDelegate(commsDataReceive);

    }

    private void handleModeSendWater()
    {
        if (moistureAdcValue <= 500)
            moistureWet = true;
        else
            moistureWet = false;
        if (moistureAdcValue <= 500 && moistureDry != moistureWet)
            sendDataToWindows("WaterLevel=" + moistureAdcValue + " wet");
        if (moistureAdcValue > 500 && moistureDry != moistureWet)
            sendDataToWindows("WaterLevel=" + moistureAdcValue + " dry");
        moistureDry = moistureWet;

        if (strDataReceived.Equals("SENDBUTTON"))
        {
            curMode = MODE_SENDBUTTON;
            Debug.WriteLine("===Entering MODE_SENDBUTTON===");
        }
        else if (strDataReceived.Equals("SENDALL"))
        {
            curMode = MODE_SENDALL;
            Debug.WriteLine("===Entering MODE_SENDALL");
        }
        else if (strDataReceived.Equals("SENDTEMP"))
        {
            curMode = MODE_SENDTEMP;
            Debug.WriteLine("===Entering MODE_SENDTEMP");
        }

        strDataReceived = "";
    }

    private void handleModeSendTemperature()
    {
        if (tempDegree <= 31)
            tempCold = true;
        else
            tempCold = false;
        if (tempDegree <= 31 && tempCold != tempHot)
        {
            Sleep(3000);
            sendDataToWindows("Temperature = " + tempDegree.ToString("N2") + " : cold");
        }

        else if (tempDegree >= 32 && tempCold != tempHot)
        {
            Sleep(3000);
            sendDataToWindows("Temperature = " + tempDegree.ToString("N2") + " : hot");
        }


        if (strDataReceived.Equals("SENDBUTTON"))
        {
            curMode = MODE_SENDBUTTON;
            Debug.WriteLine("===Entering MODE_SENDBUTTON===");
        }
        else if (strDataReceived.Equals("SENDALL"))
        {
            curMode = MODE_SENDALL;
            Debug.WriteLine("===Entering MODE_SENDALL");
        }
        else if (strDataReceived.Equals("SENDWATER"))
        {
            curMode = MODE_SENDWATER;
            Debug.WriteLine("===Entering MODE_SENDWATER===");
        }
    }

    private void handleModeSendButton()
    {
        if(buttonPressed != prevButtonStatus)
        {
            sendDataToWindows("BUTTON=" + buttonPressed);
        }

        prevButtonStatus = buttonPressed;
        buttonPressed = false;

        if(strDataReceived.Equals("SENDWATER"))
        {
            curMode = MODE_SENDWATER;
            Debug.WriteLine("===Entering MODE_SENDWATER===");
        }
        else if(strDataReceived.Equals("SENDALL"))
        {
            curMode = MODE_SENDALL;
            Debug.WriteLine("===Entering MODE_SENDALL");
        }
        else if (strDataReceived.Equals("SENDTEMP"))
        {
            curMode = MODE_SENDTEMP;
            Debug.WriteLine("===Entering MODE_SENDTEMP");
        }
    }
    private void handleModeSendAll()
    {
        Sleep(5000);
        sendDataToWindows("Water Level=" + moistureAdcValue);
        sendDataToWindows("Temperature = " + tempDegree.ToString("N2"));

        if (strDataReceived.Equals("SENDWATER"))
        {
            curMode = MODE_SENDWATER;
            Debug.WriteLine("===Entering MODE_SENDWATER");
        }
        else if (strDataReceived.Equals("SENDBUTTON"))
        {
            curMode = MODE_SENDBUTTON;
            Debug.WriteLine("===Entering MODE_SENDBUTTON");
        }
        else if (strDataReceived.Equals("SENDTEMP"))
        {
            curMode = MODE_SENDTEMP;
            Debug.WriteLine("===Entering MODE_SENDTEMP");
        }
    }

    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        // 
        // TODO: Insert code to perform background work
        //
        // If you start any asynchronous methods here, prevent the task
        // from closing prematurely by using BackgroundTaskDeferral as
        // described in http://aka.ms/backgroundtaskdeferral
        //

        initComms();

        startButtonMonitoring();
        startWaterMonitoring();
        startTempMonitoring();

        curMode = MODE_SENDWATER;

        Debug.WriteLine("===Entering MODE_SENDWATER===");


        while (true)
        {
            Sleep(300);

            if (curMode == MODE_SENDWATER)
                handleModeSendWater();
            else if (curMode == MODE_SENDBUTTON)
                handleModeSendButton();
            else if (curMode == MODE_SENDALL)
                handleModeSendAll();
            else if (curMode == MODE_SENDTEMP)
                handleModeSendTemperature();
            else
                Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: Invalid Mode. Please check your logic");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How are the 2 wired together? What output are you seeing on the Pi? I would think the code for the `DataComms` class would be more helpful to us than what you have here.

Comment: What is the difference there? Are You using 2 visual studios with just different account? Or is it on different computer?

Comment: Different computer